# java.io.FileNotFoundException: videos.txt (The system could not find the file)

Tags: javafx, media, filereader

I'm working on a infinite media player for a  proyect, and I got this error everytime. I've tried with Buffered Reader, FileReader, etc, but all my classmates are using Scanner and they're fine. Please help me, I have 2 days trying to find out what's wrong with my code.

The line that's giving me problem is:

```
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("videos.txt"));
```

My file is in other package and I already imported it.

This is my class. I have a main to try it, and all the imports required.

```
public class Multimedia {
    Media video;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    MediaView mView;
    
   
    public static CircularDoublyLinkedList<Media> cargarVideos() throws FileNotFoundException{
        CircularDoublyLinkedList<Media> listaVideos = new CircularDoublyLinkedList<>();
        try{
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File("videos.txt"));
            while(sc.hasNextLine()){
                String linea = sc.nextLine();                
                // System.out.println(linea);
                Media videoMedia = new Media(new File(linea).toURI().toString());
                listaVideos.addLast(videoMedia);
            }
        }catch(FileNotFoundException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return listaVideos;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are opening a file from the current directory, not your src/resources folder.  Do you mean to be bundling the text file into your .jar file?  That is the main reason you would put it in your resources folder, but then you should access it with different APIs as you can't open a file that is internal to a jar that way.

Something like this:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/video.txt"));
```